# Does node mysql allows updating multiple rows through one query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) with node and I have to update multiple rows and I want to do it with one single query. I was able to insert multiple rows but I'm not able to update multiple rows, below is the code snippet

```
var update_tasks="UPDATE tasks SET phy_1_id=? , phy_2_id=? where id=?";
                  db.query(update_tasks,[[-1,-1,10086],[-1,-1,10087]],function (er, results, fields){
                      if (er) {console.log("Error "+JSON.stringify(er));return res.status(500).send(er);}
                      else{
                        return res.status(200).json(results);
                      }
                  })
```

Can you tell me how should I go about this.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but it shouldn't be like that. The parameter query depends on column data type, for example string, convert your array to string  before update the column

```
var pkId = 'unique12312'
var update_tasks="UPDATE tasks SET phy_1_id=? , phy_2_id=? where id=?";
   db.query(update_tasks,[[-1,-1,10086].toString(),[-1,-1,10087].toString(), pkId],function (er, results, rows, fields){
      if (er) {
         console.log("Error "+JSON.stringify(er));
         return res.status(500).send(er);
      } else{
         return res.status(200).json(results);
      }
 });
```

Comment: For updating a single row I passed [-1,-1,10086] and it works, also the data types for all the columns in update statement is bigint

Comment: I don't think the query in your question will work. It's big int not array, the parameter you gave is an array. In addition, you don't specify whereclause id in the query statement.